# firefox gtk-dialog "save as" offers a file name without extension

Tags: firefox, gtk, slackware

[image]

how to return the file extension (html for example) to the default file name?

i am using slackware 14.2

Comment: Please add the bottom part of the dialog. The behaviour is not the same if it is a normal download or if you are trying to save the web page (in that case you are going to get a _files folder with resources and a .html page, no matter what you do.

Comment: made a full dialog box